# Changing the Homebrew Apache PATH variable

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew

I've recently installed Apache 2.4 on my Mac via Homebrew. (I previously used the Apple-supplied Apache.)

In a PHP script, I call Exec(x) on a executable located in /usr/local/bin, but it fails  because /usr/local/bin is not included in Apache's PATH environment variable. Running phpinfo() shows that PATH is /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin.

I had previously included /usr/local/bin in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/151328/setting-apache2-path-environment-variable), but it no longer works, I think because I'm using Apache installed by Homebrew.

My shell $PATH includes many directories including /usr/local/bin, so that's not it.

I'd rather not call Exec with an absolute path since I need to run this in several environments where the executable is in different paths.

How do I modify the Homebrew Apache's PATH variable? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://toggen.com.au/blog/it-tips/setting-the-apache-2-4-path-environment-variable-in-a-brew-services-started-httpd-process).

To change Apache environment variables when Apache was installed with Homebrew, edit the homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist file located in /usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/your version of Apache/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.httpd24</string>
  <!-- add this -->
  <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
  <dict>
   <key>PATH</key>
   <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin</string>
  </dict>
  <!-- end add -->
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>FOREGROUND</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then restart Apache.